# jQuery selector only first-level div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Given this HTML:

```html
​<div class="foo">
    select this
    <div class="foo">​don't select this</div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
    select this
</div>
```

What would be the selector to grab just the divs on the first level, not the nested one?

So the query `​$('.foo WHATEVER').length` should return 2.

See the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/Ge7qL/)** here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?  Where foo is not a descendant?

```
$('.foo').not('.foo .foo').length
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DmDBV/

Comment: Does anyone know if this solution is more efficient than $('body > .foo').length;?

Comment: If your element is going to be a children of body.. then $('body >foo') will probably be more efficient since it searches for only children elements

Comment: I think this solution is less efficient but more flexible as the html structure can be different and the divs doesn't have to be direct children. Great solution, this works for me, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `>` child selector:

```
$('body > .foo').length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pSBxv/

Comment: +1 and thank you very much but this doesn't work if the div's are no direct children of body, so unfortunately this is not very flexible (however this answers my question perfectly).

Comment: @Marc You are welcome, you can replace body with parent of the .foo elements.

Comment: Yes I know but they don't have a common parent in my project so the `$('.foo').not('.foo .foo')` works best for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `body` as a parent element and select children of it using the [Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$('body > .foo').length
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ge7qL/1/)